# Do the Boundary Value Analysis & Equivalence Class Partation for, 0<=x<=100 (here value for x is not defined,consider it is in between 0-100).

Tags: testing

Do the Boundary Value Analysis & Equivalence Class Partation for,

0<=x<=100 (here value for x is not defined,consider it is in between 0-100).

(Please mention most accurate outcomes as answer for ECP & BVA seperately)

(The above question is asked,​ as it was in one of certification exam also)

Answer (score 0):

According to me:

`BAV` for above example should be

(0, x-1, x, x+1, 100)

and `ECP` for the same should be

(x-1, x+1)   OR   (Round[(0+x)/2], Round[(x+100)/2]

Note: `ECP` is subset of `BVA`